# Re-run PL/SQL script command

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, scripting

I have a simple insert script that I want to expand upon.

```
DECLARE 
i varchar2(3000) := dbms_random.string('A',8);
BEGIN

INSERT INTO BUYERS 
(USER_ID,BUYER_CD,BUYER_ENG_NM,REG_DT)
VALUES 
(i,'tes','test','test');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHER 
THEN
(this is where I need help)

end;
```

We have dynamic replication going on between two DB's. However, for some odd reason we have to run a script twice for the changes to commit to both DB's for that reason I am creating a script that will attempt to do a insert amongst all tables. As of now I'm only working on one table. Within the exception handler how do I make the script run again when the initial insert fails? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: dynamic replication doesn't just happen without some code. Rather than trying to "Fix" a problem show us the code that does the replication and any error messages.  I hope for your sake that there is none of "when others then null" in the code.

Comment: There's so many triggers and jobs running with our replication that I simply would't be able to share them here. This script is not a fix. The purpose of this script is to verify that records are being inserted. We are aware of the issue and are working on a fix. And no are exception handlers that are " when others then null". I just want to be able to rerun a set of inserts upon failure.

Answer (score 0):

If a problem happens with the insert then the best approach is to find out what the error is and raise the error.  This is best accomplished by an autonomous logging procedure that will record the what, where, when and then RAISE the error again so processing stops.  You do not want to take a chance of inserting records once, twice or not at all which could happen if the errors are not raised again.
The LOG_ERROR procedure below can be created from the answers to your previous questions about error handling.

```
  DECLARE 
    i varchar2(3000) := dbms_random.string('A',8);
    BEGIN

INSERT INTO BUYERS 
(USER_ID,BUYER_CD,BUYER_ENG_NM,REG_DT)
VALUES 
(i,'tes','test','test');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHER 
THEN
--by the time you got here there is no point in trying to insert again
LOG_ERROR(SQLERRM, LOCATION);
RAISE;
end;
```

Comment: I see what your'e saying and it makes sense. However, all I really need is to run the statement again because I know it will fail. I'm not sure if I'm making sense at all. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jules I'm sure it is difficult to put the issue into a test case.  If all you need is to do the same thing twice then put the insert into the when others handler.  It will fail again for the same reasons...or should...